# Is ByteTrust and legit company

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees

I would like to know if ByteTrust is legit! I have ask for a withdrawal from my account since 01/05/2024.  First they ask for a deposit of 20% of the total sum (which I submitted) in order to take the money out (they say will be return to me once I get the funds.)  It is 03/30 today and now they want a 5% miner fee before I can get my funds. My question is this a scam to extract more money from me?  Should I give them the 5%.  Need Help?

Chino